# How do I use Rails console to define relationship between has_one/belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism

Hi I would like to be able to define the has_one/belongs_to relationship in Rails console. I am using Rails 4 (if that matters). After reading through some other threads I have tried a few things, but here are my models first.

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :patient
end
```

and

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :appointments
end
```

I have seen that an attr_accessor may need to be created, but my instructor was able to do it without it in either class, and I would like to emulate that if possible. I have tried:

```
a = Appointment.create(date: "9/9/15", patient_id: 2)

=> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'patient_id' for Appointment.
```

and

```
a.patient = s  //after defining both (s being patient)
 => ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `patient_id`
```

as well as a few other approaches, but I will spare you all the copy paste. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates you have not defined a column called `patient_id` in your `appointments` table.

You need to introduce this column via a [migration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), not via the Rails console. The Rails console is a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) environment with access to your model layer, it has nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: after looking at my instructors files again I see he did actually create a foreign key in his schema.